# Unable to save connections in Remmina

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I just intalled Ubuntu Unity 23.04. Then, using Synaptic, I installed Remmina v. 1.4.29. I DID NOT use Snap to install Remmina.  When I open Remmina, all I get is the Quick Connect toolbar, nothing else. After I connect to my server, I don't see any options to save the connection.

I've been doing some searching online and find that others have had this problem, but I am not able to find any working solution.  I've already checked my Preferences screen and followed previous posts. I changed the Remmina data folder to the one recommended by other posts, creating the folder ~/.remmina. After closing and reopening Remmina, I see that my preferences saved, but I still cannot use the detailed view to create a connection. I only can use the Quick Connect and still cannot save the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out on my own.  The main window of this version of Remmina is very minimalistic.  However, in the notification area, if you click on New Connection, it displays the more detailed view of creating a connection that I'm used to seeing.  After you save the connection, you can find it listed when you click on the Remmina icon again in the notification area.

---

Here's the screenshot that you requested.  My computer is in Spanish, but the window layout and icons are the same.

[image: Screenshot of Remmina and menu from notification tray.]

I am using Ubuntu Unity 23.04.  At the top of the screen is the panel and notification area towards the right.  Of cours, the Remmina main window is toward the left.  If you look in the notification area, there is a miniature version of the Remmina icon.  On my computer, it is showing up to the left of the HP logo.  If you clock on this tiny icon, you will see a menu.  The first item in the menu is "New Connection".  Click on that and you will get the more advanced method of creating a connection with all the parameters that you need.  At the bottom of that you can Save and Connect.  Once you save the connection, you can find it two ways.  Once by clicking on that tiny icon in the notification area.  Second, by going to the main Remmina window.

Comment: can you add a screenshot to help others?